# How can I add an attribute to a text element in JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

How can I produce the following XML fragment using JAXB?

```
<sequence md5="1de2cf633901ff1f00785735c8ce7e70">MPTINSALRKVARVRLTSG</sequence>
```

My class is as follows:

```
@XmlType(name = "SequenceType")
public class Sequence {

    private String md5;
    private String sequence;

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getMd5() {
        return md5;
    }

    // JAXB annotation here??
    public String getSequence() {
        return sequence;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

@XmlValue on the sequence property.

```
@XmlType(name = "SequenceType")
public class Sequence {

    private String md5;
    private String sequence;

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getMd5() {
        return md5;
    }

    @XmlValue
    public String getSequence() {
        return sequence;
    }

}
```