# How do I map the inner text content of an element to a Class property?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, java-6

Say I have the following XML and Java code respectively:

```
<foo>
My text content
</foo>
```

```java
@XmlRootElement( name="foo" )
public static class Foo
{
  // This is where I want to see "My text content" stored
  private String text;

  // getters and setters
}
```

When I tried marshalling the XML, my `Foo` instance doesn't get its text property populated with value from the inner text of my `foo` element in the given XML. How do I solve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I add an attribute to a text element in JAXB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326535/how-can-i-add-an-attribute-to-a-text-element-in-jaxb)

Comment: Yes I agree. But I find that question to be misleading by its title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `@XmlValue` annotation.

```
@XmlValue 
public String getText() {
    return text;
}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/jaxb-and-complex-types-with-simple.html