# How would you unmarshall the following with JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

How would one unmarshall the following XML response with JAXB into a domain class:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<time>2014-01-14T06:24:34+00:00</time>
```

My first instinct was to use something like (short version):

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Time {
    @XmlElement
    public Date time;
}
```

but I think JAXB then sees 2 elements with the `Time` name. I also tried without using the `@XmlRootElement` annotation, but to no avail.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I map the inner text content of an element to a Class property?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13026825/how-do-i-map-the-inner-text-content-of-an-element-to-a-class-property)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using [`@XmlValue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlValue.html) instead of `@XmlElement` for the `time` field? After all, it is the *value* of the root element, rather than a sub-element.

I've now tried this with the file supplied, and it works properly.

Comment: @NicoHuysamen: Great - I was trying it at the same time. Will it really always be the root element though? You may need to do a bit more work to get it working in the context of a bigger document...

Comment: Yeah, it's a simple "test your connectivity to the API" response. The rest of the API is pretty involved, but for completeness sake I want to implement 100% of the API functionality.